# How to set clangd (eglot) to C++20?

Tags: c++, emacs, clangd

I'm not quite sure if this is the right place to ask such a question, but you could help me a lot with any hint you have! So I'm using eglot and clangd as my lsp, and I want to set clangd C++ standard to C++20.
I have tried to put -std=c++20  in compile_commands.json for every file in my project, but this haven't done any effect. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried: "-std=c++2a" ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `-std=c++2a` instead of `-std=c++20` fixed the problem.